# Angular 16 / Flask Browser Refresh - How to Redirect to 'root'

Tags: python, angular, flask, browser-refresh

I am new to Angular and have been assigned the development of a SPA UI frontend communicating with a Flask server and everything was going fine until I hit an issue of when the user hits the refresh button.

What we want to do is redirect to the application root which in this case is index.html in the templates directory. One approach I found was to use the Flask errorhandler decorator to do the redirect but this won't work because there isn't anything returned back to the Flask server when I hit the 'Refresh' button.

When I launch the application I can see in my VSCode terminal window the Flask server starting the application container and that the call to render_template is loading all of the Angular assets; however, when I hit the browser refresh button all I see is a 404 error for the page that I was on and there is no call back to the Flask server.

So my question is this if there isn't a call back to the Flask server how can I perform the redirect to the application root. Do I put some sort of javascript handler in the index template that detects the 404 condition and handles reloading itself?

TIA,
Bill Youngman

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to detect if you navigate to a route, or was browser refreshing the page.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  subscription: Subscription;
  browserRefresh = false;
  
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.subscription = router.events.subscribe((event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          browserRefresh = !router.navigated;
        }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Only thing is that the "browserRefreshed" will be true on first time loading the page. But you can use "sessionStorage", too. sessionStorage (Browser) will be deleted if the tab is closed, or a new tab is created (one session per tab). But if the open tab will be refreshed, the session will not gone. So you can check: First load, or refresh.

Comment: Flo - I'll give this a try and report back with my findings.

Comment: Just tried this and it is indeed the browser refreshing page.

Comment: If my answer helps, you can select it as answer. Thx

Comment: It didn't help Flo I'm still experiencing the issue. It's a straight browser refresh and is not communicating with the backend Flask server

Comment: A backend NEVER knows what happen in a browser. You need to send a request on browser refresh if you want that the backend knows what to do.

Comment: Thank you Flo I'll investigate this approach with my team

Comment: Flo so my attempts an having client handle this hasn't been successful.
I'm [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true}) ] and when I launch my site the url in the address bar is -- http://localhost:4200/static/#/lob-research and when I hit the refresh button I'm still getting a 404 error.

Comment: Show me your code, please. A 404 error from the backend (console) or in the browser itself?

Comment: app-routing.module.ts:

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true}) ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

lob-research.module.ts:

import { AppRoutingModule } from 'src/app/app-routing.module';

imports: [
    --- other imports --
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DataTablesModule.forRoot()
  ]

URL:

http://localhost:4200/static/#/lob-research

Was going to look into the HashLocationStrategy next

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: Flo - actually I've turned this issue over to the original Angular developer who has much more experience with Angular than I do. I have plenty of other items / issues to work on.